# Make sure that POST request was sent

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with closing window doing with javascript

I have a form:

```
<form role="form" action="/home/manager/create_client" onsubmit="closeSelf(this)" method="post"
          id="createClientForm">
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Sometimes when i push `submit`, method `closeSelf(this)` works earlier than post request is sent. 
Method closeSelf(this):

```
function closeSelf(f) {
        f.submit();
        window.onunload = refreshParent;
        function refreshParent() {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }

        window.close();
}
```

Can you help me to make sure that post request was successfully sent and only then close the window?

Comment: You would have to do this with an XMLHTTPRequest no? For example, you intercept the form being sent and send it via an XMLHTTPRequest and wait to see if it was successful or not.

Comment: Or just use the normal form action and bring the user to another page saying "You have successfully ... " and then it closes within 5 seconds.

Comment: Maybe one of those variants will be ok. I will try. Thank you.